# Chrome extension to scrape some relevant information on a web shop

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a chrome extension to scrape some relevant information on a web shop... the code below works when I filling an input field on the html (inputId) with the ID wanted...

I would like to catch mutiples ID's also these ID's are statics like, #productTitle, #productPrice, #productDesc. every page has the same ID with different content.

I don't want to fill the input every time, the users need just click addButton and copy the ID content from multiples ID's.

I was wondering if I can catch the value(just the text content) of this IDs like a shopping basket and put on a table...

```js
document.getElementById('addButton').addEventListener("click", function() {
        var docID = document.getElementById("inputId").value;
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { "action": "grab", "param": docID }, (response) => {
                displayResults(response);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of IDs and loop through it:

```
var ids = ["productTitle", "productPrice","productDesc"];

document.getElementById('addButton').addEventListener("click", function() {

ids.forEach(function(id){
    var docID = document.getElementById(id).value;
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { "action": "grab", "param": docID }, (response) => {
            displayResults(response);
        });
});
```

Comment: The console says the following:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

But if I use the console.log I can get the ids...

var docID = document.getElementById("productTitle").textContent;
console.log(docID);
Product 01

Comment: @Lucas Rocha, I had a problem in my code I updated it. You just have to remove the pound signs from the array